# Javascript Loop and array overwrite elements by the last value given

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, overwrite

1. Get date.
2. declare new array
3. small loop for test.
4. store my initial date to index 0.
5. alert to confirm function is working and the value is ok.
6. the function that adds some constant days to generate new date (working fine).
7. loop end.
8. Shows all values in the last date I generate, like replace all array element with last values.

   ```
            fx=$("#start_date").val();          
               var list = new Array();             

               for (i=0;i<3;i++){                
               list[i]=fx;                       
               alert(list[i]);                          
               fx=calc(fx,dayinfo);                
               }

               alert(list);
   ```

Comment: Use debugger and step through the code. I.e. in IE press F12 and go to Script tab. Or at least show "calc" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fx=$("#start_date").val();
            var list = new Array();

```
        for (i=0;i<3;i++){                
        list[i]=new Date(fx);                       

        fx=calc(fx,dayinfo);                
        }
```

  -

---

```
        alert(list);
```

Comment: That was missing new Date(). :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
function(i){
   list[i]=fx; 
   alert(list[i]);
   fx=calc(fx,dayinfo);
}(i)
}
```

try this

Comment: Show ur calc function

Comment: function calc(someDate,duration){
 
someDate.setTime(someDate.getTime() +  (duration * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
return (someDate);
 }

Comment: function is working fine with me and it shows the dates i want and i confirm that by alerting value (step 5).

Comment: We don't need closure in this case as we don't have any async operation.

Comment: Looks some syntax error or something, the page didn't load, no other jquery or scripts loaded. (plain screen).

Comment: Khanh, trying to build schedule, i got the start date to fx, store the start to array called list, then i go for calc function to generate next date and again store it to list array. finally the array display all elements with the last date generated and like overwrite them !!!

Comment: [08:01:44.375] SyntaxError: function statement requires a name @ http://localhost/Code/postt.php:3478.

Comment: looks for a string name for the function not number!!

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?